# Quantifiers generalized from logical connectives

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I am aware of existence of the "generalized quantifiers" as seen here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_quantifier to mean "sets of sets". Universal quantifier is a set containing the universe and existential one is a family of all the subsets of the universe but the empty set. You can create more quantifiers by inventing new sets of sets. I got it, more or less.

What I'd like to know is whether anyone pursued other way to generalize the quantifiers - as **infinite** logical **connectives**. You *can* think of universal quantifier as inifite *and* operaton (*can't you?*):

$\forall_{x\in X}: p(x) \approx \bigwedge_{x\in X} p(x) \approx p(x_1) \wedge p(x_2)\wedge\dots\wedge p(x_i)\wedge\dots$

Similarly for existential quantifier as inifite *or*:

$\exists_{x\in X}: p(x) \approx \bigvee_{x\in X} p(x) \approx p(x_1) \vee p(x_2)\vee\dots\vee p(x_i)\vee\dots$

**Has anyone found a way to do the same with other logical connectives?**

I know that all other connectives can be constructed from these two, so perhaps there is nothing to discover/invent here, but still... I find it interesting to try to evaluate the logical value for

$?_{x\in X}: p(x) \approx \Leftrightarrow_{x\in X} p(x) \approx p(x_1) \leftrightarrow p(x_2)\leftrightarrow\dots\leftrightarrow p(x_i)\leftrightarrow\dots$

which seems to depend on the (possibly infite) *parity* of the domain $X$ (whatever that means, if anything, as pointed out in the comments).

Comment: But what is the "parity" of an infinite domain ? Is $1+1+1\ldots$ even or odd ?

Comment: I don't know. It's just something that I stumbled upon when considering infinite $\leftrightarrow$.

Comment: It's not true that the universal quantifier can be thought of as an infinite AND operation, under Tarskian semantics.  You could be working in a language where there are infinitely many objects, but finitely many names for these objects. This makes it impossible to list them all in a conjunction.

Comment: @user400188 While the possible existence of undefinable elements is definitely important, the broader point about $\forall$ isn't really true. When we set up the definition of $\models$ in a structure $\mathcal{A}$, we first pass to an expansion $\hat{\mathcal{A}}$ of $\mathcal{A}$ gotten by adding new constant symbols naming each of the elements of $\mathcal{A}$. Once we've made this change in language, "$\forall$" can indeed be represented as an infinite conjunction.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I did not have a broader point about the universal quantifier other than what I said. In Tarskian semantics it cannot be thought of as a conjunction of AND operations. 
You can of course, construct other semantics where the universal quantifier can be thought of as such a conjunction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I'd like to know is whether anyone pursued other way to generalize the quantifiers - as **infinite** logical **connectives**.

Yes. In fact, this is of primary importance to the study of [*infinitary logics*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/). In some theories, the infinite conjunction and disjunction are exactly the universal and existential quantifiers, respectively.

> **Has anyone found a way to do the same with other logical connectives?**

Incidentally, I dealt with this exact problem a few months ago. Here's what I came up with:

Let $U$ be a domain and $C:\mathcal{P}(U)\not\to U$ the *choice function* on $U$ such that $C(E)\in E$ for all $E$ in the domain of $C$. For each predicate $\phi:U\to\Bbb{B}$, define the operator $\Pi^\phi_C$ according to the following:

1. for any set $E\subseteq U$,

$$\Pi^\phi_C(E)\equiv\bigg{(}\phi(C(E))\iff\Pi^\phi_C(E\setminus \{C(E)\})\bigg{)}$$

2. for any expression $P$,

$$P\iff\Pi^\phi_C(\emptyset)\equiv P$$

Suppose now that $U=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb{N}\}$ and for any $E\subseteq U$,

$$C(E)=x_i\quad \text{iff}\quad i=\min\{j\in\Bbb{N}:x_j\in E\}$$

Then:

$$\begin{align}
\Pi^\phi_C(U)&\equiv\phi(x_0)\iff\Pi^\phi_C(U\setminus\{x_0\})\\
&\equiv\phi(x_0)\iff\phi(x_1)\iff\Pi^\phi_C(U\setminus\{x_0,x_1\})\\
&\cdots\\
&\equiv\phi(x_0)\iff\phi(x_1)\iff\phi(x_2)\iff\cdots
\end{align}$$

This provides a finite means of expressing the new quantifier in terms of the logical connective $\iff$ - independently of "parity" of the set, as you put it.

That being said, I would be extremely cautious using this technique. The existence of the choice function is not provable in every theory. Even then, the *evaluation* of $\Pi^\phi_C(X)$ is another matter entirely. It is not always possible to evaluate $\Pi^\phi_C(E)$ for all $\phi$, $C$, and $E$.

In particular, if $E$ is *uncountable*, then there is no finite procedure to determine $\Pi^\phi_C(E)$ for arbitrary $C$.

**Addendum**

For each predicate $\phi$, let $\mathcal{U}_\phi$ be an ultrafilter over the powerset of the domain $U$ such that the ultrapower $\Bbb{B}^U/\mathcal{U}\cong\Bbb{B}$, then define one of the equivalence classes to be the set of infinite bi-implications whose valuation is "true."

This can be done with or without choice, but the selection of the "correct" ultrafilter can be difficult when the order on $U$ is not apparent. In most cases, it can be shown, informally, that *some* ultrafilter exists; but this information is not necessarily helpful for evaluating specific infinite statements.

Comment: I think the abstraction is getting in the way a bit, and in particular bringing $C$ into the picture muddies things. The following seems clearer to me: given a structure $U$ and a formula $\varphi$, you're interested in the existence of a map $B:\mathcal{P}(U)\rightarrow \{\top,\perp\}$ such that $B(\emptyset)=\top$ (to get us off the ground, so to speak) and for each set $M$ and each $x\in M$ we have $$B(M)\equiv\varphi(x)\leftrightarrow B(M\setminus\{x\}),$$ correct? *(Really we should talk about multisets since $\leftrightarrow$ isn't idempotent, but whatever.)*

Comment: I figured that multisets would be unnecessary, since the goal is to define the infinite connectives over a set. Besides, you can always define a non-injective function $f$ and use $\Pi^\phi_C(f,M)\equiv \phi(f(C(M))\iff\Pi^\phi_C(f,M\setminus\{C(M)\})$ to account for repeat terms.

Comment: @NoahSchweber The choice function is necessary for quantification over arbitrary sets. The expression you provide only works for finite sets. As a counterexample, consider $B^{2\mid n}(\Bbb{N})$. If you have $B^{2\mid n}(N)\equiv 2\mid1\iff2\mid2\iff\cdots$ then the subformulae evaluate as the sequence $\bot,\bot,\top,\top,\bot,\bot,\top,\top,\ldots$. On the other hand, if you have $B^{2\mid n}(N)\equiv 2\mid 2\iff2\mid4\iff\cdots2\mid 1\iff2\mid3\iff\cdots$, then the evaluation of the subformulae yields the sequence $\top,\top,\top,\top,\ldots\bot,\top,\bot,\top,\ldots$.

Comment: Choice is only relevant if you're trying to whip up a "canonical" example of such a function. That's why I phrased the question in my comment the way I did: that phrasing doesn't rely on choice at all. As you've observed, that question has a **negative** answer (whether or not choice holds); the point is that this rules out any *natural* "infinite bi-implication" operation. Of course you can construct such a thing if you want, but by the above we know it will be pretty artificial and not satisfy many nice properties.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I wouldn't expect their to be a "nice" infinite bi-implication operation in the first place - dealing with infinite-length formulas is generally a messy business. The point of this construction is solely to explain how it *can* be done, regardless of whether or not it *should* be done. Personally, I would not use this technique at all - but if the OP is interested in infinite connectives, I figure it's better to share what I have than answer with a straightforward "No." If nothing else, maybe someone else can improve upon this technique?